# Java: How to pass a dynamic amount of arguments to a method

Tags: java, javafx, methods, variadic-functions

I am writing a JavaFX app and I need to add *n* amount of `TextField` objects to a row in a `GridPane` using its `addRow` method. `addRow` accepts any number of arguments, but the amount of of `TextField` objects it receives is not hard coded. For example,

```
GridPane gp = new GridPane();
ArrayList<TextField> tf = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < user_entered_number; i++) {
    tf.add(new TextField());
}
gp.addRow(row_index, /* all elements in tf*/);
```

I wish to include all generated `TextField` objects in the `GridPane` row at `row_index` using the `allRow` method.

If this is even possible, how can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add say 5 `TextFields` at `row 0` and `column 0` in the `GridPane` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`GridPane.addRow(...)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#addRow-int-javafx.scene.Node...-) takes an `int` (the row index) and a varargs of `Node`s. You can pass an array for a varargs parameter, so you can do

```
gp.addRow(row_index, tf.toArray(new Node[0]));
```

Alternatively, just create an array instead of a list in the first place:

```
GridPane gp = new GridPane();
TextField[] tf = new TextField[userEnteredNumber];
for (int i = 0; i < userEnteredNumber; i++) {
    tf[i] = new TextField();
}
gp.addRow(row_index, tf);
```

Comment: It should be new Node[tf.size()]; not 0

Comment: @Flood2d doesn't really matter, does it? If the size of the specified array is less than the size of the list, `toArray()` will create a new array anyway. (And if you're worried about performance, etc, which is negligible here, it's better to just create an array in the first place.)

Comment: Will this put all `TextField` objects in the same node or separate nodes? That is, will `tf[0]` be at row i, column k and `tf[1]` be at row i, column k + 1?

Comment: @jshapy8 I don't understand what "Will this put all `TextField` objects in the same node or separate nodes?" means. A `TextField` is a `Node`. It will behave exactly the same as `gp.addRow(rowIndex, tf[0], tf[1], tf[2],...,tf[tf.length-1]);`

Comment: I'm asking if each `TextField` in `tf` will have a unique position in the `GridPane` row.

Comment: Yes, each node will go in a different grid cell.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem properly. Do you want to add all the elements from tf ArrayList as arguments in addRow() method?

addRow() mathod takes varargs as an argument. Did you try convert the ArrayList into array and then pass it to the method?

```
TextField[] arr = new TextField[tf.size()];
arr = tf.toArray(arr);
```